# how to pass json file content to nektos act secret configuration

Tags: nektos-act

How to include json file content in `.secrets` file when using `act -s .env=.secrets` ?

writing the json string inside the `.secrets` file works

```
   MY_SECRET_TOKEN='{"field":"value"}'
```

trying to include the json from another file does not work

```
   MY_SECRET_TOKEN=$(cat file.json)
```